# Jquery. Script changes value in input field. Than based on value in the input field need to execute if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuvGW/5/)

If enter something in First input, then value in the Second and Third input becomes 1 (one).

Then if value in Third input is `> 0` then do something, for example`alert("Test");`

But this `if` statement does not work. For my eyes value in Third input is 1 (one), but for script seems the value in Third input is empty

How to get execute `if` statement based on value in Third input?

```
First input
<br>
<td class='exchange_rate1'>
<input type="text" name="exchange_rate1" id='exchange_rate1' class='exchange_rate_changed1' value="">
</td>
<br>Second input
<br>
<td>
<input type="text" name="is_exchange_rate_changed1" id="is_exchange_rate_changed1" class='exchange_rate_changed_test1'>
</td>
<br>Third input
<br>
<td>
<input type="text" name="is_exchange_rate_changed_test1" id="is_exchange_rate_changed_test1">
</td>


$(".exchange_rate_changed1").on("change", function () {
$('#is_exchange_rate_changed1').val(1).change()
});


$(".exchange_rate_changed_test1").on("change", function () {
$('#is_exchange_rate_changed_test1').val(1).change()
});

if ($("#is_exchange_rate_changed_test1").val() > 0) {
alert("Test");    
}
```

If question why this is necessary. Then, for example:

1) in first input field user enters currency name (USD)

2) with ajax, based on currency name get currency value in the Second input

3) if currency value in the Second input changes, then changes Third input

4) and latter if user enters amount in currency in Fourth field and Third input value is `> 0`, then do calculations

**Possible solution** 
Here http://jsfiddle.net/eDCqN/11/ placed possible solution. As I need `if` to exist / work independently, then created additional function that is executed on `$("input").change`. So as understand each time when `input` changes `if` is executed. Possibly instead of `input` may use some class (add class only to necessary input fields).

Is such solution ok?

Seems this is better (shorter) http://jsfiddle.net/NJfL3/2/

Comment: Your if isn't being evaluated because it doesn't exist in an event..  In reality, it is being evaluated.. just when the document is loaded.

Comment: @Daedalus is right - here's the fixed jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VuvGW/5/

Comment: I reread. My English not so good. Where is problem with my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are adding your `if` condition separately, you need to add it inside your `change` event, like:

```
$(".exchange_rate_changed_test1").on("change", function () {
    $('#is_exchange_rate_changed_test1').val(1).change();
    if ($("#is_exchange_rate_changed_test1").val() > 0) {
        alert("Test");    
    }
});
```

Comment: Added information in question (below) why all this is necessary. And it appears that `if` need to exist/execute separately. I mean value in `is_exchange_rate_changed_test1` is 1. After some time user enters amount in Fourth input. And then `if` value in Third input `> 0` and value in Fourth input `!= ''` then execute (calculate). Will experiment ...